# Writing a web protocol

Tags: c, networking, web, network-programming, protocols

I wrote [this (quickly drafted and not finished) specification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qp9Z1SPBECeqeZc_E3n2RfAux9ScZo8OQSYgnRkorL4/edit?usp=sharing) which basically explains how I would like to write a web based protocol in c. I'm not sure how to start writing. I think that I should begin writing the tcp socket connections but Im not sure.

Comment: Couldn't you write any needed tags to the MP3 file itself?

Comment: @ChrisBode I need to include the server information

Comment: Your choice of error codes is pretty terrible, same numbers as HTTP but different meanings. And you should start writing wherever you  feel like, I don't really see what sort of input you expect from us.

Comment: @Mat Sorry. Please keep in mind that it was quickly drafted and not completely finished. It does however give the complete gist of the protocol

Comment: @user2420649 ID3 allows for custom named tags.

Comment: @ChrisBode I know. I also need to include information such as the server code or the server color

Comment: Finish the specification before you start writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are a beginner with C. Here's the list of thing you need to do:

Learn C, C sockets specifically:
1) This is an incredible place to start researching the C sockets. http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ It also teaches basic client server relationship and includes sample codes.
2) Learn the MP3 standard, this is fairly good place to start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3
3) Also look into id3 tags, which are common meta tags for mp3 audio files. id3.org should be the place to look for it.

Also remember, coding in C is not an easy thing, you need to be very careful not to mess up.

Comment: You could mark it as answer or vote up at least =)

Answer (score 1):

Btw, FTP uses TCP. So, if you are interested in building another FTP like protocol, then you should certainly stick with TCP. Else, you would end up doing a book-keeping and retransmission at the application level.

Also, to scale things up, you should certainly explore adding a select() call to your protocol server. This way, the server can not only wait for incoming file requests, but can also continue to serve the existing ones. And, if you want to scale it to really large numbers, you should also design it using multiple threads (POSIX threads for C).